# How to debug a Fast Common Gateway Interface (FCGI) program?

Tags: c++, debugging, nginx, spawn-fcgi

I encountered a problem that I don't known how to debug a FCGI program which written in C++ and based on [fastcgi](http://www.fastcgi.com/).

The program is managed by Lighttpd [spawn-fcgi](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/spawn-fcgi) and called by nginx fastcgi module.

I wrote a shell script to restart **spawn-cgi**:

```
#! /bin/bash

cgi_default="index.cgi"
process_pid="pid"

param_ip="127.0.0.1"
param_port="9000"

if [ -f "$process_pid" ]; then
    pid=`cat $process_pid`
    kill -9 $pid &> /dev/null
    rm $process_pid
fi

spawn_out=`/usr/local/bin/spawn-fcgi -a $param_ip -p $param_port $cgi_default`
# spawn-fcgi: child spawned successfully: PID: 6423
pid=`echo $spawn_out | cut -d " " -f6`
expr $pid + 0 &> /dev/null
[ $? -eq "0" ] && echo "$pid" > $process_pid
```

The program **index.cgi** was successfully built and just **printf** some strings to out stream.

And my configuration in **nginx**:

```
location / {
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
```

Now I am wroking on **index.cgi**, change some code (maybe with faulty logic). The program crashed and **502 Bad Gateway** was returned in my browser.

It's hard for me to find out what is wrong in my program because the fcgi progam acts as a callback function of nginx. So I cannot press Debug button and bebug my program normally.

So how can I debug my program properly and conveniently?

Comment: use gdb or add logging to the program, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, gdb attach the running process debugging will help a lot.