# spawn-fcgi without nginx or it's equivalent, how to get stdout

Tags: c, nginx, spawn-fcgi

I've got an installation with nginx and fastcgi. spawn-fcgi has got and argument that points to a C fcgi script `spawn-fcgi -p 8000 -n __fastcgi`. All this together functions as expected.

I want to be able to get the ouput, something like `Hello World`, without nginx.
Preferably in C. I've searched but only nginx result came up.

Looking for pointers to continue.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950094/how-to-debug-a-fast-common-gateway-interface-fcgi-program

Comment: The probllem is that `FCGI_Accept()` is not triggered. I've created a C client server and I don't know how to send the header data in the correct format to the fastcgi server.